# Angular9 + NX + Storybook : Why are my Scss styles getting ignored in Storybook ? No errors

Tags: angular, sass, storybook, nrwl-nx

Hi has anyone got Angular9+ in an NX workspace working with Storybook using Scss / Sass ?

Are there any working guides? It is not working for me so I am probably doing something wrong.
(new to Storybook & NX)
The app works fine - the Sass is used with no problems, but is ignored in Storybook.
I have followed many examples but the styles are not getting applied.

I am using the NX App-shell and Libs methodology.
Advice from others online is that Libraries do not use Styles imports in Angular.json

I have tried the solutions from here (but not working for me) https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/5684

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a link to your scss in your .storybook/config.js file using the sass-loader  like:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../../shared/styles/src/lib/main.scss';
```

reference: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6364#issuecomment-485651328

Comment: Thanks @johann but I tried this with multiple Libs in my project and it does not work for me.

Comment: Same here, I've done this but the theme fails to load. I had this working before at some point. I'm wondering if an update messed things up